# Twython update status not working even after OAuth1 keys

Tags: twython

What am I missing here I've went through the OAuth1 instructions as listed [here](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/starting_out.html#authentication) and have gotten the proper access_key and access_secret but still I am not able to update status.

```
>> from twython import Twython
>> t = Twython('consumer_key','consumer_secret','access_key','access_secret')
>> t.update_status("test")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: update_status() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I am though able to make `get_user_timeline()` calls.

Could this be an account ban of some sort perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact! You need to explicitly define the parameter. Not entirely sure why this is but here is the solution.

```
t.update_status(status='test')
```

Comment: It's throwing an error because you're passing more arguments than the function `update_status` (which is a Twython function expects, not a Twitter function)


See https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/endpoints.py#L94-L100